# Angular SCSS animation not working on Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, angular, google-chrome, sass

I haven't tested every browser, but the animation doesn't work on Safari and Chrome (It does work on Opera tho).
The code is in Angular, styles - SCSS.

When I launch the website with the live server (from my PC) everything works fine, but when I deploy it on [Netlify](https://www.netlify.com/) and change the website resolution to mobile, the **"circle-opacity-mobile"** animation doesn't work (on Chrome and Safari).

```
.box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 6rem;
    height: 6rem;
    border-radius: 6px;
    background: #d8a6a6;
    box-shadow: inset 8px -3px 10px #7f6262, inset -8px 3px 10px #ffeaea;

    /* Animation properties */
    animation-name: circle-opacity;
    animation-duration: 7s;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    cursor: pointer;

    /* Adjust the position */
    transition: 0.5s;
    text-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

@keyframes circle-opacity {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-25vh) rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(-25vh) rotate(-190deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg) translateY(-25vh) rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@keyframes circle-opacity-mobile {
    0% {
        transform: rotate(0deg) translateY(-18vh) rotate(0deg);
    }
    50% {
        transform: rotate(180deg) translateY(-18vh) rotate(-190deg);
    }
    100% {
        transform: rotate(360deg) translateY(-18vh) rotate(-360deg);
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width:526px) {
    .box {
        animation-name: circle-opacity-mobile;
        width: 4rem;
        height: 4rem;
    }
    .box span {
        font-size: 0.6rem !important;
    }

    .box:hover span {
        font-size: 0.7rem !important;
    }
}
```